# event's are not getting added

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>  
<head>  
<title></title>
<!--binding handlers to object-->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function showAuthor()
{
alert("oscar wilde");  
}
function enableEvent()
{
document.getElementById('someText').attachEvent("onmouseover",showAuthor);              
}               
function disableEvent()
{
someText.detachEvent("onmouseover",showAuthor);
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="enableEvent();">
<em id="someText">we may be in the gutter ,but some of us are looking at the stars</em>
<form action="#" method="get">
<input type="button" value="Attach event" onclick="enableEvent();" /> 
<input type="button" value="Detach event" onclick="disableEvent();" />
<input type="button" value="show author" onclick="showAuthor();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used the above code to implement event handlers, but when I execute the program event handlers are not attached. Why?

Comment: you seem to be attaching a `mouseover` event, upon `onclick`. so, are you trying to display `showAuthor` only on `mouseover` and that too, only when the element is first clicked?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
document.getElementById('someText').attachEvent("onmouseover",showAuthor);
```

should have been like this

```
document.getElementById('someText').addEventListener("mouseover",showAuthor, false);
```

You don't want to attach an event but you want to add an event listener.

Furthermore, you don't want to detach any event but you want to remove an event listener, whose syntax is like this:

```
document.getElementById("someText").removeEventListener("mouseover",showAuthor, false);
```

```js
var someText = document.getElementById("someText");

function showAuthor(){
    alert("oscar wilde");  
}

function enableEvent(){
    someText.addEventListener("mouseover",showAuthor, false);         
}            

function disableEvent(){
    someText.removeEventListener("mouseover",showAuthor, false);
}
```

```html
<body onload="enableEvent()">
<em id="someText">we may be in the gutter ,but some of us are looking at the stars</em>
<form action="#" method="get">
<input type="button" value="Attach event" onclick="enableEvent()" /> 
<input type="button" value="Detach event" onclick="disableEvent();" />
<input type="button" value="show author" onclick="showAuthor()" />
</form>
</body>
```

For a detailed explanation of the above, please have a look at the following links:

- [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [EventTarget.removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: i have just executed the code but the program is still not working

Comment: @Dilkush I am sorry, I forgot to remove the on part from the event. It is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you need to use `addEventListener`. And when using `addEventListener`, you do not need to put an "on" prefix with the event names.

***Snippet:***

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showAuthor() {
    alert("oscar wilde");
  }

  function enableEvent() {
    document.getElementById('someText').addEventListener('mouseover', showAuthor);
  }

  function disableEvent() {
    document.getElementById('someText').removeEventListener('mouseover', showAuthor);
  }
</script>

<body onload="enableEvent();">
  <em id="someText">we may be in the gutter ,but some of us are looking at the stars</em>
  <form action="#" method="get">
    <input type="button" value="Attach event" onclick="enableEvent();" />
    <input type="button" value="Detach event" onclick="disableEvent();" />
    <input type="button" value="show author" onclick="showAuthor();" />
  </form>
```

Hope this helps.